# Birkhoff's Erogdic Theorem and scaling of a random process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, ergodic-theory

I have a question regarding the Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem and time scaling of a random process:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a given probability space and let $\{ X(k,\omega_k), k\geq 0\}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) random variables with $\mathbb{E}(|X(0,\omega_0)|) < \infty$. According to Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem, it follows that

\begin{align} \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i = 0}^k X(i,\omega_i) = \mathbb{E}(X(0,\omega_0)). \end{align}

Now, what I want to do is to scale the same random process $\{ X(\varepsilon k,\omega_{\varepsilon k}), k\geq 0\}$ with a constant $\varepsilon > 0$. Can I directly apply Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem again?

\begin{align} \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i = 0}^k X(\varepsilon i,\omega_{\varepsilon i}) = \mathbb{E}(X(0,\omega_0)) \end{align}

Or do I have to factor in the constant $\varepsilon$?

\begin{align} \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i = 0}^k X(\varepsilon i,\omega_{\varepsilon i}) = f(\varepsilon) \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i = 0}^k X(i,\omega_i) = f(\varepsilon) \mathbb{E}(X(0,\omega_0)) \end{align}

where $f$ is a function depending on $\varepsilon$.

Or do I violate the requirement of a measure preserving transformation $T: \Omega \to \Omega$ in this case and thus cannot make any statements regarding the scaled random process?

As you can see, I'm a little bit confused right now since I'm fairly new to this topic. I would be very happy if someone could help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you see what's going on if $\epsilon=1/2$, or if $\epsilon$ is some other rational?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your hint yet. Could you give me a tip on what I should investigate regarding the constant $\varepsilon$?

Comment: It's not a hint so much as an inquiry into what you've tried, to see if there are special cases you do know how to handle.  By the way, do you mean $X(\lfloor\epsilon i\rfloor,\omega)$?

Comment: So I've tried to be a little more specific with my question by editing it. What I am interested in is what happens or what I can deduce if I use the same sample path, but speed up $(\varepsilon < 1)$ the random process, so to speak. Is it possible to make any statements about the limit value in this case?